# Copying file from network into local directory

Tags: java

I want to copy a file from network location into my local directory. I have written following code for this, but the problem is, it needs to have a file created first, and then the out stream writes the bytes stream into this file.

What i want is, the precondition to first create file locally should not be there. It should simply copy the network file into the mentioned directory directly, thats it! I'm kind of doing this for the first time.

```
try {
    File srcFile = new File("//network//file//path//here");
    File dstFileName = new File("//local//drive//file//path//here");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstFileName);

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
        out.write(buff, 0, length);
    }
        in.close();
        out.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: "i need to have a file created locally first" - what makes you say that?

Comment: what i mean is, it writes the data into the file and if file is not present then i get FileNotFound Exception. So i need to have a file in local destination directory

Comment: Just google create file java!

Comment: I know to create a file, but can't this be done without thatt, can't i just copy the copy into my local drive...just copy

Comment: Surely if you need to create a file you could just execute `dstFileName.createNewFile();` before you try writing to it?

Comment: Not unless the file already exits, what do you expect it to write to if you don't create a file for it?

Comment: The `FileOutputStream` creates a file for you if it doesn't exist, but it might throw a `FileNotFoundException` if it cannot create it. Check the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29). So you should check what the Stacktrace tells you, about why it could not create this file.

Comment: ok..i just used dstFileName.createNewFile();...thx @user4387909

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the file, before you can write to it.

```
if(!dstFileName.exists()){
   dstFileName.createNewFile();
}
```

If the the path does not exist, you can try to create it first with

```
dstFileName.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Comment: The `FileOutputStream` creates the destination file, if it doesn't exist. It throws `FileNotFoundException` if it cannot create this file. So I don't think that `dstFileName.createNewFile();` can do that instead.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Then maybee the path does not exist or is not
accesible.

Comment: Maybe. It is up to OP to check the stacktrace for more information about the problem.